# PHP file_exists() sees file although it doenst exist

Tags: php, php-7

I'm using PHP's file_exist() Function to upload files (and dont get them double). Unfortunately, even when the folder is empty it says file exists. When i upload manually and let it check again it doenst recognize it as double. - Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $directoy = $_POST['kategorie'];
  $heading = $_POST['headline1'];

  $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];

  $endung = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $custom_path = 'files/'.$directoy."/".$heading.".".$endung;
  $default_path = 'files/'.$directoy."/".$file;


  if(empty($heading)){
      $exist = file_exists($default_path);
      if($exist=0){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $default_path);
      }else{
        echo "Dateiname exisitert bereits!<br><br>";
      }

    }else{
      $exist = file_exists($custom_path);
      if($exist=0){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $custom_path);
      }else{
        echo "Dateiname exisitert bereits!<br><br>";
      }
  }
?>
```

When the folder is empty: File exists
When I put it in manually: File exists
When I change it to if(exist==1) it works once but it doenst make any sense to me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: There is a difference between = and == in php, = is assignment and == is comparison. effectively, ```$exist=0``` will always return false, so ```if(false) {} else{ // this will always happen }```

Comment: Obviously, I'm an idiot! Thank you very much - lack of concentration - I'm very glad that you found that silly mistake! Best regards, MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between = and == in php.
`=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

Effectively, `$exist=0` will always return false, so

```
if(false) {

} else{ 
     // this will always happen 
}
```